# Transfer selected feature points to a new variable

Tags: matlab, feature-extraction, feature-detection

I'm planning to transfer only a few feature descriptors which have been classified using SVM. I tried to put the selected descriptors in a matrix but I can't match them properly. Here's the code that I made in order to transfer the selected descriptors to another variable.

```
[nrows, ncolumns] = size(fdImage);
SVMResultFace = svmclassify(SVMStructFace, fdImage);
ClassifiedFace = [];
for row = 1:nrows
    if SVMResultFace(row,1) == 1
        ClassifiedFace = [ClassifiedFace; fdImage(row,:)];
    end
end
```

is there a more proper way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to eliminate those rows from fdImage is just to use logical indexing:

```
SVMResultFace = svmclassify(SVMStructFace, fdImage);
include_row = SVMResultFace(:,1) == 1;
ClassifiedFace = fdImage(include_row,:);
```